# Run/install/debug android app wirelessly but over its own portable hotspot

Tags: android

we know how to develop and connect wirelessly over Android phone to Android Studio. 
Is there a way to connect to same mobile which internet we are using by making portable hotspot ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have done it for long time. connect the laptop to you phones hotspot, then go to the about phone->status see the ip address and the connect mobile with laptop with usb cable and run command `adb tcpip 5555` then `adb connect <your ip addrss>` Now you can disconnect your usb cable. Your mobile will be shown in the run dialog.
Note: you must have adb on your pc and its path declared in the environment variables.